# Encoding Surnames with Gender Variations (Greek, Czech, Russian, etc) in Gramps?

Tags: surnames, gramps, gender

### Background:

> In some cultures, such as Greek, Bulgarian, Russian, Slovak, Czech, etc. surnames change form depending on the gender of the bearer. For example, ...in Slovakia and Czech Republic alike, if a man is called Novák, the wife adds a feminine suffix "-ová" to his surname after the marriage, hence Nováková. The same is true for daughters which almost always inherit the father's surname with the feminine suffix. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surname))

### Task

For simplicity's sake, let's say that for filtering, statistical, and similar purposes, I need some surnames to be treated as equivalent.

> Novák = Nováková
>   Obama = Obamová
>   ...

This does not qualify as a 2nd surname, but like a variable prefix - but it cannot be done automatically either, as there are exceptions to the gender morphing.

I'm using Gramps, but interested in how this is handles in general.

Answer (score 2):

Each name in Gramps can have an associated "Group as name", "Sort as name", and "Display as name" when listing, sorting, and displaying, respectively. However, I don't think any of those are used for filtering on surname.

Answer (score 2):

In my family database, many surnames have variant spellings. I use metaphone (which strips vowels and substitutes some consonants) to group related surnames. I had to create a custom-field for this, but some programs may be able to generate it automatically.

(Caveat: this works for filtering and statistics, but not if you wanted some way to generate the appropriate ending in report sentences).